# How to created Stack Data table for non blank values in the columns in R

Tags: r

I have data something like this (Stakeflow colleagues support to get this. Thank you all.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name-1 | Name-1 |  | Name-1 |
| Name-2 |  |  | Name-2 |
| Name-3 |  | Name-3 |  |
| Name-4 |  |  |  |
| Name-5 | Name-5 |  | Name-5 |

Now I want to get data something like this from above result. Can anyone help me to on this please?
I need to get other data cuts one of them is this in which I Stuck.

| CT | OG.Name |
| --- | --- |
| B | Name-1 |
| B | Name-5 |
| C | Name-3 |
| D | Name-1 |
| D | Name-2 |
| D | Name-5 |

Comment: `df1 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = B:D)` and then you can remove `NA` or empty values if needed.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah Thanks a lot. I was looking for the solution that I can replicate for big data. I can nit fixed the columns. Can you suggest the changes accordingly ?

Comment: Can you provide sample of your actual data preferably using `dput` ?